# How to get Selected Row of WPF Devexpress TreeList in .NET?

Tags: .net, wpf, devexpress, treelist

I am new to Devexpress controls. I have added `TreeList` control on form an bind it using Entity. I want to get the selected column value i.e ID

In .Xaml file:

```
<dxg:TreeListControl Name="treeListContacts" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource EntityServerModeDataSource2}}" AutoPopulateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="317" Width="180" FocusableChanged="treeListContacts_FocusableChanged">
            <dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Company_ID" ReadOnly="True" Width="30" Visible="False"/>
                <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CompanyName" ReadOnly="True"/>
            </dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
            <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
                <dxg:TreeListView ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
            </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
        </dxg:TreeListControl>
```

Here, now i want to get the selected company id?
Help Appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Code-behind way**:
You can obtain the value of the specified cell contained within the focused row via the [TreeListView.GetNodeValue](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTreeListView_GetNodeValuetopic) method using the following code snippet:

To learn more, see [Obtaining and Setting Cell Values](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6150).

```
<dxg:TreeListControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource EntityServerModeDataSource2}}" AutoPopulateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="317" Width="180" FocusableChanged="treeListContacts_FocusableChanged">
    <dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Company_ID" ReadOnly="True" Width="30" Visible="False"/>
        <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="CompanyName" ReadOnly="True"/>
    </dxg:TreeListControl.Columns>
    <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
        <dxg:TreeListView ShowTotalSummary="True" x:Name="treeListView"/>
    </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
</dxg:TreeListControl>


//...
object id = treelistView.GetNodeValue(treelistView.FocusedNode, "Company_ID");
```

**MVVM way**:
You can define the FocusedRow property in your ViewModel and bind it to the [TreeListView.FocusedRow](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_FocusedRowtopic) property.

Comment: Sorry @DmitryG i have tried this code in 'FocusableChanged' event but it wont work. Error: Doesnt contain defination for 'GetNodeValue' :(

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE Which version you are using? Please ensure that the `x:Name` is asigned to the treelist view.

Comment: yes offcourse i am using the 'Name' please see in markup above. i am using vs2012 ultimate. and devexpress 12.2 version. & how to prevent row focus by default when page loads for the first time?

Comment: My code snippet works fine to me (i've also using vs2012prof and 12.2). Does the original answer is resolved for you?  
As for the second question - i believe this question is not related to original one and it is better to start the new thread. (as far as I know when the TreeList is bound to the ItemsSource it should always had the Focused node.  Please refer to http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q390182.aspx for possible Workaround)

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE  - in your markup there is no `x:Name` attribute for the **TreeListView** (only Name property for TreeListControl)